# How to combine async and blocking requests in VuGen?

Tags: long-polling, loadrunner, vugen

I'm working on a load test for my long-poll chat-like service. The use case I want to test is fairly simple:

1. Open a long-poll GET connection
2. Send a message using POST request
3. Assert that connection opened in step 1 has received the same message

I managed to implement steps 1 and 2 (and I can see in server access logs that requests are made) but on step 3 I'm getting following error:

> Error -27653: Attempted read from an unconnected socket ("Connection:
>   close" specified but server-side closure not detected).
>   URL="https://{Env}/chat/poll/"    [MsgId: MERR-27653]
>
> Warning -27764: Request "https://{Env}/chat/poll/" failed   [issued at Action.c(76)] 
>     [MsgId: MWAR-27764]

Can I combine async requests with blocking requests?

My test code is

```
int done;

Action()
{
    int HttpRetCode;
    int i = 5;

    // Initialize the global done state variable, and start the async transaction variable
    done = 0;
    lr_start_transaction("async-call");

    // Define the request to be handled asynchronously
    // Specify the callback functions that will be called when the response is returned.
    // The callback functions are defined below.     
    web_reg_async_attributes("ID=Poll_0",
        "URL=https://{Env}/chat/poll/",
        "Pattern=LongPoll",
        "PollIntervalMs=200",
        "RequestCB=Poll_0_RequestCB",
        "ResponseBodyBufferCB=Poll_0_ResponseBodyBufferCB",
        "ResponseCB=Poll_0_ResponseCB",
        LAST);

    // now make the async call.
    // note that the script will not block on this call.  processing will continue on past this step while the request is handles asynchronously
    web_url("Poll_0",
        "URL=https://{Env}/chat/poll/",
        "Resource=1",
        LAST);

    lr_force_think_time(10);

    // Send interop message
    lr_message("Send interop message");

    lr_start_transaction("/chat/.POST.201");

    web_add_header("X-Session-ID", "sessionA");

    web_custom_request("Push interop message",
                       "URL=https://{Env}/chat/",
                       "Method=POST",
                       "Resource=0",
                       "Mode=HTTP",
                       "Body=DJIGURDA",
                       LAST);

    HttpRetCode = web_get_int_property(HTTP_INFO_RETURN_CODE); 

     if (HttpRetCode != 201) {  
        lr_error_message("Unexpected return code: %d", HttpRetCode); 
        lr_end_transaction("/chat/.POST.201", LR_FAIL); 
    } else {ev
        lr_end_transaction("/chat/.POST.201", LR_AUTO);
    }

    lr_message("Waiting for response");

    // To capture the response time of the async call, wait until the callback is called.
    // Without this, the script would move past and complete the iteration before the callback is called.     
    //web_sync("ParamCreated=ready","RetryIntervalMs=18000","RetryTimeoutMs=3600000",LAST);
    // To capture the response time of the async call, wait until the callback is called.
    // Without this, the script would move past and complete the iteration before the callback is called.
    while (done==0 && i-- > 0)
    {
        lr_force_think_time(1);
    }

    // once the callback has been called, end the transaction to get the response time.      
    lr_end_transaction("async-call", LR_AUTO);

   // stop the polling
   web_stop_async("ID=Poll_0",
        LAST);

    return 0;

}

/*
*    Callback Implementation
*
*
*/

int Poll_0_RequestCB()
{
    //enter your implementation for RequestCB() here
    lr_message("in Poll_0_RequestCB request callback");

    return WEB_ASYNC_CB_RC_OK;
}

int Poll_0_ResponseBodyBufferCB(
    const char *    aLastBufferStr,
    int                aLastBufferLen,
    const char *    aAccumulatedStr,
    int                aHttpStatusCode)
{
    //enter your implementation for ResponseBodyBufferCB() here

    // when the response is received, update the global variable
    done = 1;

    // print out the response body and length
    lr_message("in Poll_0_ResponseBodyBufferCB response body callback");
    lr_message("in Poll_0_ResponseBodyBufferCB response body callback, lastBufferLen=%d", aLastBufferLen);

    return WEB_ASYNC_CB_RC_OK;
}

int Poll_0_ResponseCB(
    const char *    aResponseHeadersStr,
    int                aResponseHeadersLen,
    const char *    aResponseBodyStr,
    int                aResponseBodyLen,
    int                aHttpStatusCode)
{
    //enter your implementation for ResponseCB() here

    lr_message("in Poll_0_ResponseCB response callback, headerLen=%d, bodyLen=%d", aResponseHeadersLen, aResponseBodyLen);
    lr_message("in Poll_0_ResponseCB response callback, header=%s", aResponseHeadersStr);
    lr_message("in Poll_0_ResponseCB response callback, body=%s", aResponseBodyStr);

    return WEB_ASYNC_CB_RC_OK;
}
```

And the log output is:

```
Action.c(19): Notify: Transaction "async-call" started.
Action.c(25): web_reg_async_attributes started      [MsgId: MMSG-26355]
Action.c(25): Warning -26318: When "Pattern" is not "Poll", "PollIntervalMs" is ignored     [MsgId: MWAR-26318]
Action.c(25): web_reg_async_attributes highest severity level was "warning"     [MsgId: MMSG-26391]
Action.c(36): web_url("Poll_0") started     [MsgId: MMSG-26355]
Action.c(36): "ID=poll_0" && "Pattern=LongPoll" now applied to URL="https://{Env}/chat/poll/" (RelFrameId=1, Internal ID=3)     [MsgId: MMSG-35172]
in Poll_0_RequestCB request callback
Action.c(36): Retaining cross-step download of URL="https://{Env}/chat/poll/" (RelFrameId=1, Internal ID=3)     [MsgId: MMSG-27658]
Action.c(36): web_url("Poll_0") was successful, 0 body bytes, 0 header bytes    [MsgId: MMSG-26386]
Action.c(41): lr_force_think_time: 10.00 seconds.
Send interop message
Action.c(46): Notify: Transaction "/chat/.POST.201" started.
Action.c(48): web_add_header("X-Session-ID") started    [MsgId: MMSG-26355]
Action.c(48): web_add_header("X-Session-ID") was successful     [MsgId: MMSG-26392]
Action.c(50): web_custom_request("Push interop message") started    [MsgId: MMSG-26355]
Action.c(50): Retaining cross-step download of URL="https://{Env}/chat/poll/" (RelFrameId=1, Internal ID=3)     [MsgId: MMSG-27658]
Action.c(50): Retaining cross-step download of URL="https://{Env}/chat/poll/" (RelFrameId=1, Internal ID=3)     [MsgId: MMSG-27658]
Action.c(50): Retaining cross-step download of URL="https://{Env}/chat/poll/" (RelFrameId=1, Internal ID=3)     [MsgId: MMSG-27658]
Action.c(50): web_custom_request("Push interop message") was successful, 0 body bytes, 377 header bytes     [MsgId: MMSG-26386]
Action.c(58): web_get_int_property started      [MsgId: MMSG-26355]
Action.c(58): web_get_int_property was successful   [MsgId: MMSG-26392]
Action.c(64): Notify: Transaction "/chat/.POST.201" ended with "Pass" status (Duration: 1.3904 Wasted Time: 0.0033).
Waiting for response
Action.c(76): lr_force_think_time: 1.00 seconds.
Action.c(76): Error -27653: Attempted read from an unconnected socket ("Connection: close" specified but server-side closure not detected). URL="https://{Env}/chat/poll/"      [MsgId: MERR-27653]
Action.c(36): Warning -27764: Request "https://{Env}/chat/poll/" failed   [issued at Action.c(76)]      [MsgId: MWAR-27764]
Action.c(76): Notify: Deleting Conversation Information with ID="poll_0"
Action.c(76): lr_force_think_time: 1.00 seconds.
Action.c(76): lr_force_think_time: 1.00 seconds.
Action.c(76): lr_force_think_time: 1.00 seconds.
Action.c(76): lr_force_think_time: 1.00 seconds.
Action.c(80): Notify: Transaction "async-call" ended with "Pass" status (Duration: 19.0076 Think Time: 16.5943 Wasted Time: 0.0043).
Action.c(83): web_stop_async started    [MsgId: MMSG-26355]
Action.c(83): Warning -26000: Failed to find conversation with ID="poll_0" for stopping     [MsgId: MWAR-26000]
Action.c(83): web_stop_async highest severity level was "warning"   [MsgId: MMSG-26391]
Ending action Action.
```

I'm using VuGen 11.52 and C API